# rocket chip riscv rtl simulation

Tags: simulation, riscv, bare-metal, register-transfer-level

I write a bare metal application and generate the machine code, write it to the axi memory registers in testbench, and directly run the simulation, the simulation can complete.
There are some store instructions (sd, sw, etc), but the axi interface only has read actions, there's no write actions on the axi interface for all the store instructions.
Here's my bare metal application and the waveform, can anybody help me please?

```
0000000080000000 <_start>:
    80000000:   30047073                csrc    mstatus,8
    80000004:   30405073                csrw    mie,0
    80000008:   00002197                auipc   gp,0x2
    8000000c:   ff818193                add     gp,gp,-8 # 80002000 <c.0>
    80000010:   00003117                auipc   sp,0x3
    80000014:   ff010113                add     sp,sp,-16 # 80003000 <_sp>
    80000018:   00000297                auipc   t0,0x0
    8000001c:   06828293                add     t0,t0,104 # 80000080 <trap_vector>
    80000020:   30529073                csrw    mtvec,t0
    80000024:   3051f073                csrc    mtvec,3
    80000028:   00012283                lw      t0,0(sp)
    8000002c:   00512423                sw      t0,8(sp)
    80000030:   00000513                li      a0,0
    80000034:   00000593                li      a1,0
    80000038:   7c9000ef                jal     80001000 <main>
    8000003c:   020010ef                jal     8000105c <_postmain_fini>
    80000040:   10500073                wfi
    80000044:   ffdff06f                j       80000040 <_start+0x40>
        ...
```

Disassembly of section .text.trap:

```
0000000080000080 <trap_vector>:
    80000080:   f6010113                add     sp,sp,-160
    80000084:   00113023                sd      ra,0(sp)
    80000088:   00413423                sd      tp,8(sp)
    8000008c:   00513823                sd      t0,16(sp)
    80000090:   00613c23                sd      t1,24(sp)
    80000094:   02713023                sd      t2,32(sp)
    80000098:   02a13423                sd      a0,40(sp)
    8000009c:   02b13823                sd      a1,48(sp)
    800000a0:   02c13c23                sd      a2,56(sp)
    800000a4:   04d13023                sd      a3,64(sp)
    800000a8:   04e13423                sd      a4,72(sp)
    800000ac:   04f13823                sd      a5,80(sp)
    800000b0:   07013823                sd      a6,112(sp)
    800000b4:   07113c23                sd      a7,120(sp)
    800000b8:   09c13023                sd      t3,128(sp)
    800000bc:   09d13423                sd      t4,136(sp)
    800000c0:   09e13823                sd      t5,144(sp)
    800000c4:   09f13c23                sd      t6,152(sp)
    800000c8:   341022f3                csrr    t0,mepc
    800000cc:   06513023                sd      t0,96(sp)
    800000d0:   342022f3                csrr    t0,mcause
    800000d4:   04513c23                sd      t0,88(sp)
    800000d8:   34202573                csrr    a0,mcause
    800000dc:   00010593                mv      a1,sp
    800000e0:   7b1000ef                jal     80001090 <core_trap_handler>
    800000e4:   06013283                ld      t0,96(sp)
    800000e8:   34129073                csrw    mepc,t0
    800000ec:   05813283                ld      t0,88(sp)
    800000f0:   34229073                csrw    mcause,t0
    800000f4:   00013083                ld      ra,0(sp)
    800000f8:   00813203                ld      tp,8(sp)
    800000fc:   01013283                ld      t0,16(sp)
    80000100:   01813303                ld      t1,24(sp)
    80000104:   02013383                ld      t2,32(sp)
    80000108:   02813503                ld      a0,40(sp)
    8000010c:   03013583                ld      a1,48(sp)
    80000110:   03813603                ld      a2,56(sp)
    80000114:   04013683                ld      a3,64(sp)
    80000118:   04813703                ld      a4,72(sp)
    8000011c:   05013783                ld      a5,80(sp)
    80000120:   07013803                ld      a6,112(sp)
    80000124:   07813883                ld      a7,120(sp)
    80000128:   08013e03                ld      t3,128(sp)
    8000012c:   08813e83                ld      t4,136(sp)
    80000130:   09013f03                ld      t5,144(sp)
    80000134:   09813f83                ld      t6,152(sp)
    80000138:   0a010113                add     sp,sp,160
    8000013c:   30200073                mret
```

Disassembly of section .text:

```
0000000080001000 <main>:
    80001000:   fd010113                add     sp,sp,-48
    80001004:   02813423                sd      s0,40(sp)
    80001008:   03010413                add     s0,sp,48
    8000100c:   00050793                mv      a5,a0
    80001010:   fcb43823                sd      a1,-48(s0)
    80001014:   fcf42e23                sw      a5,-36(s0)
    80001018:   00100793                li      a5,1
    8000101c:   fef42623                sw      a5,-20(s0)
    80001020:   00200793                li      a5,2
    80001024:   fef42423                sw      a5,-24(s0)
    80001028:   fec42783                lw      a5,-20(s0)
    8000102c:   00078713                mv      a4,a5
    80001030:   fe842783                lw      a5,-24(s0)
    80001034:   00f707bb                addw    a5,a4,a5
    80001038:   0007871b                sext.w  a4,a5
    8000103c:   00018793                mv      a5,gp
    80001040:   00e7a023                sw      a4,0(a5)
    80001044:   00018793                mv      a5,gp
    80001048:   0007a783                lw      a5,0(a5)
    8000104c:   00078513                mv      a0,a5
    80001050:   02813403                ld      s0,40(sp)
    80001054:   03010113                add     sp,sp,48
    80001058:   00008067                ret

000000008000105c <_postmain_fini>:
    8000105c:   ff010113                add     sp,sp,-16
    80001060:   00813423                sd      s0,8(sp)
    80001064:   01010413                add     s0,sp,16
    80001068:   010007b7                lui     a5,0x1000
    8000106c:   06178793                add     a5,a5,97 # 1000061 <__stack_size+0xfff861>
    80001070:   00779793                sll     a5,a5,0x7
    80001074:   deadc737                lui     a4,0xdeadc
    80001078:   eef70713                add     a4,a4,-273 # ffffffffdeadbeef <_sp+0xffffffff5ead8eef>
    8000107c:   00e7a023                sw      a4,0(a5)
    80001080:   00000013                nop
    80001084:   00813403                ld      s0,8(sp)
    80001088:   01010113                add     sp,sp,16
    8000108c:   00008067                ret

0000000080001090 <core_trap_handler>:
    80001090:   fe010113                add     sp,sp,-32
    80001094:   00813c23                sd      s0,24(sp)
    80001098:   02010413                add     s0,sp,32
    8000109c:   fea43423                sd      a0,-24(s0)
    800010a0:   feb43023                sd      a1,-32(s0)
    800010a4:   00000793                li      a5,0
    800010a8:   00078513                mv      a0,a5
    800010ac:   01813403                ld      s0,24(sp)
    800010b0:   02010113                add     sp,sp,32
    800010b4:   00008067                ret
```

Disassembly of section .bss:

```
0000000080002000 <c.0>:
    80002000:   0000                    .2byte  0x0`
```

[image: waveform]

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion would be that your Rocket Chip system uses a cache (which is usually the case). With that, your store instructions will write data to the cache. As long as the cache is not flushed, there will be no write actions on the axi interface.
If you want to write to AXI memory registers, that are also used by other components, the MMIO (memory-mapped input-output) AXI port (instead of the MEM port) should be used.
With the MMIO port, the cache is not used.

By defaut the Generated Address Map is as follows (you should see that in the chisel elaburation output)

```
Generated Address Map
           0 -     1000 ARWX  debug-controller@0
        3000 -     4000 ARWX  error-device@3000
       10000 -    20000  R X  rom@10000
     2000000 -  2010000 ARW   clint@2000000
     c000000 - 10000000 ARW   interrupt-controller@c000000
    60000000 - 80000000  RWX  mmio-port-axi4@60000000
    80000000 - 90000000  RWXC memory@80000000
```

So you have to make sure the registers you want to use are in the MMIO address range (`0x60000000 - 0x80000000`)

Alternatively, forcing a cache flush could also work. However, I have never tried to figure out how to do this.
If the data needs to be written out immediately and/or could be accessed from a different component than rocket-chip (e.g. a co-processor) you should definitely use the MMIO port.

Comment: Thank you so much, sounds reliable, I'll give it a try!
Also, maybe I can also try to disable cache, because it is used in a real-time application, cache is not needed.
Maybe I need to do some modification in the rocket chip scala source code and generate verilog without cache, it'll be realy helpful if you know something about this...

Comment: The MMIO port solution works, thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. You can adjust the size of the cache in src/main/scala/subsystem/Configs.scala. Wherever RocketTileParams is defined. (depending on what core config you are using.) Maybe you could try to just set the parameters to zero (e.g. nSets=0). This would generate a cache with size zero. However, I have never tried this and I am not sure if it would be advisable.